Ubuntu 22.04.5: mdns resolution not working for accessing VM guest
running on "Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS" as host (hostname blackbird) and I created a VM guest("Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS", hostname pg1) using "Virtual Machine Manager 4.0.0" using KVM as hypervisor.
Unfortunately I cannot use mdns for accessing my guest from the host machine.
Here is the virbr0 from the host:
blackbird:/home: ip addr show virbr0
4: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:48:82:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Here is the network config from Virtual Machine Manager for the guest:

This is the network config from the guest:
pg1:/home/guenter: ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:9f:dc:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.219/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft 3338sec preferred_lft 3338sec
    inet6 fe80::5ab4:cf13:1af1:27d5/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Pinging the guest via mdns fails but using the IP works
blackbird:/home: ping pg1.local
ping: pg1.local: Name or service not known
blackbird:/home: ping 192.168.122.219
PING 192.168.122.219 (192.168.122.219) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.122.219: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.17 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.122.219: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.687 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.122.219: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.743 ms

I think I've missed something, but could not find what
